# how to use object for dependent variable in sample.split

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Is it possible to pass an object for the dependent variable in sample.split?

This works where Exited is the dependent variable.

```
set.seed(880)
split = sample.split(ds$Exited, SplitRatio = 0.65)
```

This doesn't work passing an object for the dependent variable.

```
dv <- "Exited"
set.seed(880)
split = sample.split(ds$dv, SplitRatio = 0.65)

Error in sample.split(ds$dv, SplitRatio = 0.65) : 
      Error in sample.split: 'SplitRatio' parameter has to be i [0, 1] range or [1, length(Y)] range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[[` instead of `$` for extraction

```
sample.split(ds[[dv]], SplitRatio = 0.65)
```